# Firefox Issue: The connection to wss://web_page_address was interrupted while the page was loading

Tags: firefox, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

I am getting the above error on Firefox 63 on Ubuntu 16.04. On Chrome, everything works perfectly. It *sometimes* works as it should on Firefox, but a lot of the time, when I load the page, the websocket transportation between the server and client doesn't happen, then I get the above error in the console after about a minute. I don't refresh or do anything--I just load my application normally in Firefox.

I'm running a Flask-SocketIO application as socketio.run(app) on a CentOS server with eventlet installed for concurrency. I pass in my host IP address and run it on port 443, passing in a self-signed certificate and associated key. I see in the network tab that a GET 101 is made, marking the switch to the websocket protocol, so it seems to be working well. Moreover, the app works perfectly fine on localhost in Firefox, so I'm suspecting there is a websocket/self-signed certificate Firefox bug that is causing this, but I'd like to narrow it down or confirm this somehow.

Comment: Based on the dependencies that you have, the websocket support comes from Eventlet, so if there is a problem with the websocket implementation that is where you should look for it. You may want to try the gevent + gevent-websocket combination to see if the outcome is different.